# Batch for move Zero Bytes Files, Check and create a Log?

Tags: batch-file, logging, move, zero

I really need help,
Is it possible to create a Batch for compare Zero Bytes Files (if stays in folder for more than 2 minutes) move Zero Bytes Files (in `C:\start` into another folder `C:\end`) , Check if it's done, if isn't start all over again and create a Log?

I'm using to move

```
@Echo off
for %%I IN (*.*) DO if %%~zI==0 Move C:\start C:\end
```

But I don't have any ideas of how can I compare the file and create a Log, can someone help?

Comment: Can you please explain further, I'm having trouble understanding

Answer (score 0):

**(This is a partial answer...)**

To fill the log file at the same time as you move the files, you can do that:

Instead of calling the command `move` you can call another batch file, that I call moveandlog.bat:

```
  [File: moveandlog.bat]
  move %1 %2
  echo %1>>C:\thelog.txt 

  [File: maintask.bat]
  @Echo off
  for %%I IN (*.*) DO if %%~zI==0 call moveandlog.bat C:\start\%%I C:\end
  ECHO The following 0 size files has been moved to C:\end,
  ECHO.
  TYPE C:\thelog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
for %%I IN (*) DO if %%~zI==0 Move "C:\start\%%~I" "C:\end" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo File %%~I successful moved.
    ) || (
    echo ERROR: file %%~I NOT moved!
)
```